# How are keywords in metadata stored?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I'm researching options to synchronize external data to a Category and Keyword list.

I have a metadata field with a `states` field that uses a category called US States.

When I preview my component with a simple XSLT component template (`<xsl:copy-of select="." />`), I can see:

```
<tcm:Content>
...
</tcm:Content>
<tcm:Metadata><Metadata xmlns="http://createandbreak.net/schema/generic">
<states>California</states>
<states>New York</states>
</Metadata></tcm:Metadata>
```

When I update the keyword and preview, I can see updated values.

```
<tcm:Content>
...
</tcm:Content>
<tcm:Metadata><Metadata xmlns="http://createandbreak.net/schema/generic">
<states>Californias</states>
<states>New York</states>
</Metadata></tcm:Metadata>
```

Which is great. It looks like we *do not* need to synchronize components (open, edit, and save)  to use updated keywords. Is that a safe assumption?

**If I update a keyword, do I need to update components that use it in order to publish component presentations with the updated values?**

Do I need to also be careful when moving components with content porter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need to do anything manually for those Keyword fields to be "Content Porter"-safe. Tridion stores the link from your Keyword field to the Keyword definition (in the category) as a so-called managed link (a TCM URI).

The reason you don't see this value in your XSLT has to do with the way Tridion traditionally exposes the Keywords in WebDAV: it hides the TCM URIs there and instead just exposes the value of the selected keyword. Since Keyword values must be unique within their category, this will always allow you to look up the correct TCM URI if needed.

But when exporting (and in general when you're using the API to access content) you should retrieve the Component XML with the TCM URIs in place. Check the API documentation for your programming language to see which Filter/ReadOption you need to specify for that.

Comment: Always nice to get a "no extra work needed" response. I updated the WebDAV part into a clearer question that matches your answer.